# Move 1 record from List of Figures to next page

Tags: captions

I was searching for a while for a solution but could not find one. Hope you can help me guys. I want to make whole 3.4 record on next page, because otherwise it just breaks like that and it looks awfull. The problems looks like this:
[image: Break it!]

Caption is added like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{higgs}
    \caption{Kanały rozpadu bozonu Higgsa.}
    \figsource{źródło: \url{http://atlas.physicsmasterclasses.org/en/zpath_hboson.htm} \newline dostęp: 16.01.2016} 
        \label{higgs} 
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

And \figsource is defined like that:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\scriptsize}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
{\leftskip\cftfigindent
 \advance\leftskip\cftfignumwidth
 \rightskip\@tocrmarg
 \figsourcefont#1\protect\par}%
  }%
 }
\makeatother
```

The figsource was copied from internet and to be honest do not know what it does but it works :P. Iam kinda new to Latex so please be forgiving.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  It best to provide a complete minimal document (see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) removing unnecessary features from the code.  For example, the `\usegraphics` can be replaced by simple text.  One could add second optional argument to `\figsource` allow you to insert a command, e.g. `\clearpage` after the `\par`.  A more natural way in LaTeX would be to provide some negative penalty encourage a page break.

Comment: The new command with \clearpage after \par worked! Thanks and next time i will do a complete minimal document!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crude way to this would be to extend the definition of the command `\figsource` to allow insertion of extra code, such as `\clearpage`, after the final `\par`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsource}[2][\relax]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
{\leftskip\cftfigindent
 \advance\leftskip\cftfignumwidth
 \rightskip\@tocrmarg
 \figsourcefont#2\protect\par #1}%
  }%
 }
\makeatother
```

In this short example we break after the second entry:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\scriptsize}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsource}[2][\relax]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
{\leftskip\cftfigindent
 \advance\leftskip\cftfignumwidth
 \rightskip\@tocrmarg
 \figsourcefont#2\protect\par #1}%
  }%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\figsource{A}
\figsource[\clearpage]{B}
\figsource{C}

\end{document}
```

Better would be to use `\\*` rather than `\newline` in your entries.  `\\*` is a linebreak followed by `\nopagebreak`.  Then you don't have guess which `\figsoure`  to add the `\clearpage` to.  You might need to set the list of figures `\raggedbottom` for that to work well.